# Trying to use window.onbeforeunload to trigger function

Tags: javascript, html, function

In a webpage I am creating I want to disconnect from a connection automatically upon the closing of the page, yet it refuses to work. The disconnect function exists in an external .js file that is correctly referenced in the head.

```
<script>
    window.onbeforeunload = disconnect;
</script>
```

I previously changed it from "disconnect();" to "disconnect;". There was no change in result. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Where is the definition of `disconnect`?

Comment: try this: **https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/beforeunload**

Comment: @myfunkyside That' the same as the OP uses

Comment: @hindmost - must have missed that line where he adds the event-listener then..

Answer (score 0):

Because I have no idea what "**disconnect**" does, here is a simple example of how to bind a function to the `window.onbeforeunload` event:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    // bind a function to the window.onbeforeunload event
    window.onbeforeunload = function(event) {
      // your disconnect() function
      disconnect();
      // bad ui, but for example - prompt user to verify they want to leave the page
      prompt("Are you sure you want to leave this page?");
      // log to the developer tools console that this event fired
      console.log("onbeforeunload event fired");
    };

</script>
```

Hopefully that helps. It looks like the problem may be in how you have `disconnect()` defined.